# Can stolen cars be impounded?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've been playing the story mode for GTA V PC and as Michael, I came across an Infernus and started driving it around. I probably started a mission and got an alert that my Infernus was impounded.

Later, after forgetting about this, I drove past the impound lot and noticed the car symbol (white) inside. I payed the $250 and retrieved the Infernus. I read that a car has to be modded or bought to be impounded.

Is this supposed to happen? Will it continue to become impounded until I buy insurance for it?

Comment: The insurance is for online. Sometimes cars, which drive around are already tuned. Normally you have to save it in your garage.

Comment: I also have gta v for pc and the same happens to me, if I steal a car it gets impounded. I dont think its supposed to happen but it does

Comment: It's also annoying if you have a car you did modify and want to keep but the impound lot is full with random cars so your car just despawns.

Answer (score 1):

At least offline, I couldn't find a way to do it except for using the garages (in the safe houses or the bought one). The better solution I found to have a good car at reach is tuning the characters original cars. A note on the subject, the Michael's car changes 2 times along the story.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stolen cars can be impounded in Story Mode. But I would advise you to use the characters' default vehicles when triggering missions as Story Mode is notorious for purchased and stolen cars (modded or not) going missing forever.

Even vehicles that are stored in a purchased garage are not protected and must **always** be returned to the garage after driving them. (Unlike planes, boats and helicopters.)